# Windows Floating abrir diferentes actividades sin detener la anterior

Tags: android

Estoy creando una APP que principalmente se usa desde un Windows Float estilo al que usa Facebook Messenger, al pulsar sobre el se abre varias opciones (botones)

Por ejemplo el primero abre la aplicación google Maps, el segundo una Actividad interna, etc...

Lo que sucede es que si abro desde Windows Float Google Maps, y desde el Windows Float abro una actividad y vuelto a pulsar en el icono de Google Maps, esta se abre desde cero como nueva, perdiendo el destino o lo que se tenia.
Y si vuelvo a la CallsActivity sucede lo mismo se ha detenido la actividad alcambiar perdiendo lo que tenia.

```
        ImageView gpsButton = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.btn_GPS);
    gpsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Service_SoftKeysFloat.this, "GPS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // mode:
            //      d -> Auto
            //      w -> a pie
            //      d -> en bicicleta
            // avoid
            //      t -> evitar peajes
            //      h -> evitar autopistas
            //      f -> evitar transbordadores
            // San Martin Coordenadas: 40.389932, -4.372887

            //Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Calle Bureba 26,Leganes&mode=d&avoid=tf");
            //Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            IntentGPS = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            IntentGPS.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            if (IntentGPS.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(IntentGPS.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY));
            }

            // Cierra la lista de opciones
            expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            collapsedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    //Set the Call button.
    ImageView callButton = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Calls);
    callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Service_SoftKeysFloat.this, "Calls.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            IntentCalls = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallsActivity.class);
            startActivity(IntentCalls.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY));

            // Cierra la lista de opciones
            expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            collapsedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que cada vez que haces click sobre tus "Botones" recreas una actividad nueva. Si lo que quieres es resumir las Actividades una vez iniciadas debes utilizar:

`startActivityIfNeeded` los parametros que reciben son los siguientes, segun la [documentacion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startactivityifneeded) oficial:

> **Parámetros**
>
> **intent:** es de tipo `Intent` describe el intent o activity a lanzar Este valor nunca debe ser null.
>
> **requestCode:** es un `int` y si el valor es >= 0, este código se devolverá en el resultado cuando la actividad finalice, como se
>   describe en startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
>
> **options:** es un `Bundle`, es decir ppciones adicionales sobre cómo debe iniciarse la actividad. Este valor puede ser null.

En tu caso deberias iniciar las `Activitys` de la siguiente manera:

```
startActivityIfNeeded(IntentGPS.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), 0);

startActivityIfNeeded(IntentCalls.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), 0);
```

Tal como su nombre lo dice, solo disparara la creacion de la Actividad (`onCreate`) cuando se requiera (si no esta creada). De lo contrario si ya esta iniciada disparara los otros métodos de su ciclo de vida. El flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` es para reordenar dicha Activity al frente del Stack.

**Nota:** Ten en cuenta que si vas a utilizar dicha forma de llamar a las Activitys, debes manejar sus ciclos de vida con los listeners que afectan el hardware del móvil. Por ejemplo si en una pantalla utilizas el `PowerManager` o el sensor de proximidad, para apagar y encender la pantalla o saber si un objeto esta cerca o lejos. Si no quitas la sucripcion a esos listeners en una Actividad no activa. Dichos listeners se estarán disparando constantemente hasta que se destruya la Actividad que los maneja. La recomendación es que en el `OnPause/OnResume` hagas el set de los listeners de manera correcta.